# VBA Refreshing Data Connection by selecting a new text file without adding a new table

Tags: vba, excel, data-connections

So I've been trying to figure out how to do this but I am only able to get VBA to add new connections and not refresh the current one (without prompting the user).

Basically, I have multiple things that need to be refreshed at once and it would be far easier if I could just run this macro and have it do all of the refreshes for me without me having to manually select the dozen or so text files.

So far, the only version of this that I have been able to get to work is the following:

```
Set RefreshWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).QueryTables _
.Add(Connection:=strFilename, _
Destination:=declinerefresh.Cells(1, 1))

With RefreshWorkbook
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
End With
```

Unfortunately, this means that every time I run this script, it creates new connections in the workbook. I am hoping to be able to run some sort of script that will basically refresh the workbook and open the new file without needing any user input (because every day I have to run a bunch of different reports and compile them for comparison, oh and I can't delete the old ones).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` ? or Workbook("<<Your Workbook Name>>").RefreshAll`

Comment: So I was trying to come up with a way to avoid that dialog box and tell Excel which files to get with minimal user input.

Basically, I have VBA look at the 8 folders and grab the most recent document from each.

I am doing this to try and cut down on human error because sometimes people pull incorrect documents.

Comment: Why not delete the old connection connections?

Comment: Apparently the most simple solutions escape me.

Go figure.